# How do I figure out the time in Robert Goodman's memories?

Tags: cognition-an-erica-reed-thriller

In *Episode 1: The Hangman*, I need to work through Robert Goodman's memories of his wife. I have figured out things like the dress color, the date, the station, etc. However, I have no clue how to figure out the time.

When I ask Robert about it directly, he says he doesn't remember the time. I've listened to the evidence tape and he says that he "looked down at my cell phone and said it was our time", then admits it was an inside joke. Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to ask Robert about that. I thought it might be something like them sharing the same birthday, but the people database shows that this isn't the case.

How can I figure out the time that Robert Goodman last remembers his wife?

<sub>I would appreciate an answer that contains hints, with the solution in a spoiler tag.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Figured out the answer myself, but answering for the benefit of anybody else.</sub>

You're on the right track. Robert did say on the tape that "it was our time" and that is a likely candidate for how to figure it out.

**Hint 1:**

> Robert might be a bit unnerved if you were to ask him out of the blue what "our time" means.

**Hint 2:**

> You'll need to find some way to prompt him for the information.

**Hint 3:**

> It wasn't your new powers that led you to think of "our time". What was it?

**Solution:**

> Show Robert the tape recorder. Once he hears the phrase, he will explain what "our time" means.